# Codeigniter cannot redeclare class

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Not: Its work just one time in loop. Its return this error for other time.**

I have a usermodel.php in models. When i use it like

```
$this->load->model("Usermodel");
$user = $this->Usermodel->quer(1);
```

it throw "Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$Usermodel"

When i use

```
$this->load->model("Usermodel");
$user = new Usermodel();
```

it throw "Message: Cannot redeclare class Users"

user class has construct and desturct functions. I call it in Usermodel.php file. And usermodel has construct and destruct functions.

```
<?php 
class User {
        public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
}
private $id;
private $email;
private $name;
private $profilPic;
private $topPic;
private $gender;
private $birthday;

private function setid($id){
    $this->id = $id;
}
private function getid(){
    return $this->id;
}
private function setemail($email){
    $this->email = $email;
}
private function getemail(){
    return $this->email;
}
private function setname($name){
    $this->name = $name;
}
private function getname(){
    return $this->name;
}
private function setprofilPic($profilPic){
    $this->profilPic = $profilPic;
}
private function getprofilPic(){
    return $this->profilPic;
}
private function settopPic($topPic){
    $this->topPic = $topPic;
}
private function gettopPic(){
    return $this->topPic;
}
private function setgender($gender){
    $this->gender = $gender;
}
private function getgender(){
    return $this->gender;
}
private function setbirthday($birthday){
    $this->birthday= $birthday;
}
private function getbirhday(){
    return $this->birthday;
}

public function __set($name, $value){
    $functionname = 'set'.$name;
    return $this->$functionname($value);
}
public function __get($name){
    $functionname = 'get'.$name;
    return $this->$functionname();
}

public function __destruct(){}
}

?>
```

This is usermodel

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Usermodel extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->view("Users.php");
        $this->load->model("Dbmodel");
    }
    public function quer($id){
        $uqcont = array("id" => $id);
        $uiqcont = array("userID", $id);
        $uq = $this->Dbmodel->control("user", $uqcont);
        $uiq = $this->Dbmodel->control("userinfo", $uiqcont, $limit=1, 'userID');
        $user = new Users();
        if($uq->num_rows()==1){
            $uq = $uq->result();
            $user->id=$id;
            $user->name=$uq[0]->name;
            $user->email=$uq[0]->email;
            $user->profilPic="girlprofil.png";
            $user->topPic="arka.jpg";
        }
        if($uiq->num_rows()==1){
            $uiq=$uiq->result();
            if($uiq[0]->profilPic){
                $user->profilPic = $uiq[0]->profilPic;
            }
            if($uiq[0]->topPic){
                $user->topPic = $uiq[0]->topPic;
            }
        }
        return $user;
    }

    public function __destruct(){}

}
?>
```

This is a part of my view.php

```
foreach($query->result() as $row){
     $cont = array("id" => $row->userID);
     $query = $this->Dbmodel->control("user", $cont);
     $this->load->model("Usermodel");
     $user = new Usermodel();
     $user = $user->quer($row->userID);
     $date = new datetime($row->date);
     $date = $date->format("d.m.Y H:i:s");

     //$query = $query->result();
     //foreach($query as $qur){
     echo '$user->name.'<br>'.$row->comment;

     //}
     //unset($user);
}
```

Please look to my error and help me to solve it.

[image: This is my error]

[image: Error image]

Comment: Well you have a syntax error in the `view` part, missing the closing `'`. That's not this problem though.  You also don't need to do this in the `Users` class `parent::__construct();` as it has no extends.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix this is epic detect. How i cant se it :D

Comment: I would just be guessing, the way CI loads classes is garbage though. There isn't enough here to know, a stacktrace might be hellpful

Comment: I dont have sytanx error friend. I edit it in here. So my error on here.

Comment: You don't need to load the model inside the foreach(); you just do it once.

Comment: Also the error refers to a "Users" class, which is different from your "User" class. It must be in a different file and you must be declaring the class "Users" multiple times.

Comment: @twistedpixel he seems to be doing that in his view. could be the issue? better question is is that a view or a controller with all that code ;p

Comment: @BadDiscoverer You need to make some Good Discoveries by reading the Codeigniter User Guide on how to use Models...

Comment: Why loading view in model?

Comment: @twistedpixel i moved it over foreach. I think my problem is the User class is not destructed after used.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 i use it like include() or require().

Comment: @BadDiscoverer but views() are for controller. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: @wolfgang1983 it doesnt matter. i can use it without problem if only i need one User. When i need more than one user then it throw error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change this "class Users" to "class users extends CI_Model" and i move "$this->load->model("usermodel") on over of loop. Then the problem is solved. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

the class `User` is being declared more than once, probably in the loop you were referring to.

is this line in the loop?

```
$this->load->model("Usermodel");
```

if so try moving it out of the loop.

Comment: next guess would be this line `$this->load->view("Users.php");`

Comment: Did you see my error picture at end of my post? The error is "cannot redeclare user"

Comment: yes. that means that you are loading the `user` class in your loop, which results in this error. the line in my comment above is where I would check next.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to loading the model several times in the foreach loop. Load it only once then create instances of the class as many times as you wish

```
 $this->load->model("usermodel");
    foreach($query->result() as $row){
         $cont = array("id" => $row->userID);
         $query = $this->Dbmodel->control("user", $cont);
         $user = new Usermodel();
         $user = $user->quer($row->userID);
         $date = new datetime($row->date);
         $date = $date->format("d.m.Y H:i:s");
    }
```

Then consider using small caps in your load->model().
I advise loading the data in the controller then passing the data to the view. Let the controller have most of the logic.For example in the controller

```
$this->load->model('usermodel');
$data['users'] = $this->usermodel->quer($id)->result();
$this->load->view('users_view', $data);
```

In the view its as simple as

```
foreach ($users as $user)
{
//logic e.g. echo $user->name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$this->load->model("X")` is doing something like following;

1. Check models directory if X.php exists and if it exists
   it creates the class with the given name in our case "X", [ `$this->X = new X();` ]
   you can also pass the alternative name to the load->model method like
   `$this->load->model("X","my_x_model")`, in that case the loader  module  will create

   $this->my_x_model = new X();

It was just to give some information about "what happens when you trying to load a model"

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an Undefined property because

```
 $this->load->model("usermodel");
```

has to be in lowercase.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#loading-a-model

Comment: This isn't the solution to the current problem but it will solve his next problem :)

Comment: what do you mean @twistedpixel ?